# Can I know the position of bluetooth 5.1 beacons using a bluetooth 4.0 device?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on a project that places bluetooth beacons in a map.
I can choose between a bluetooth 4.0 beacon or an bluetooth 5.1 beacon.
With bluetooth 4.0 i can use RSSI to kinda locate the position of the beacon
but with bluetooth 5.1 accurate positioning is possible.
The Angle of arrival and Angle of Departure concept are very strange to me.
If the bluetooth beacon is 5.1 i should probably use Angle of Arrival but i cant find any code or example anywhere.

My question in short:
If i have a bluetooth 5.1 beacon can i listen to its position using something like a Raspberry pi or bluetooth 4.0/5.0 phone? or should the receiver also have 5.1?

Thanks in advance :)